# Thoughts on Cauchy criterion for sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence $a_n$ is Cauchy, then we must have $||a_n - a_m || < \epsilon$ **for all** $n,m>N$. However, I've seen that people have been assuming $n>m$, stating that this is without loss of generality. If $n>m$, we'll leave out those $m>n>N$ or even the trivial case $n=m$. Comments?

I once remember that I came up with a proof that every monotonically decreasing sequence is Cauchy but that holds for any $n$ but for $m=n+1$ and not all $n,m$ (counterexamples?) but it was declared incorrect for the same reason.

I couldn't comment on the specific question because this website discourages questions to answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$|a_m-a_n|=|a_n-a_m|$$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$